# OnPostExecute() of asynctask is not called first time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask in my application. But first time onPostExecute() is not getting called. After that from next time its calling. What can be the problem?

This is how I invoke AsyncTask -

```
new NotificationListAsyncTask(this, notificationCountHandler).execute();
```

And below is my AsyncTask -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class NotificationListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
Context context;
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private Handler handler;
public static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_COUNT = "key_notification_count";
public static final int KEY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = 1001;
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATION_ID = "ID";

public NotificationListAsyncTask(Context context, Handler handler) {
    this.context = context;
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler(context);
    UrlBuilder builder =AppService
            .getAppService().getUrlBuilder();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = null;
    try {
        jsonStr = requestHandler.makeServiceCall(
                builder.getNotificationListUrl(
                        CommonFunctions.getuserId(context),
                        CommonFunctions.getUtcTime(context)),
                RequestHandler.GET);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray contents = null;
            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contentsEnclosed = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
            contents = contentsEnclosed.getJSONArray(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = contents.getJSONObject(i);
                String jsonValue = obj.toString();
                String contentId = obj.getString(TAG_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                AppService.getAppService().insertNotification(jsonValue, contentId);
            }
            CommonFunctions.setNotificationrequestTime(context);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("RequestHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);        
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(KEY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Shows us how you invoke asynctask and the asynctask code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. use below code in application class oncreate() method -

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It worked for me but still don't know why its needed or is it the correct way. And previously all AsyncTask was working perfectly. I don't know what happened that it started with such behaviour that now its not working for first time. If anyone knows please explain.

Comment: I also dont know,Thats why I asked for it.

Comment: this is not required at all. It should work if doInbackground executed fines. Read the docs.